# How can I fix my sprite being rotated 90 degrees more than toward the mouse?

Tags: mathematics, libgdx, mouse, trigonometry, ruby

I am trying to get a Sprite in LibGDX to look at the player's mouse. Here's the code I have (mind you, I am using JRuby):

```
target = mouse_position.sub(spatial.position)
rotation = MathUtils.atan2(target.y, target.x)
spatial.rotation = rotation * MathUtils.radiansToDegrees
```

This is definitely doing *something*, but it's not completely correct. Here's a GIF of what it looks like in action:

[image: Rotation gone wrong]

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Looks like your results are simply offset by 90 degrees - try adding that to the rotation?

Comment: Either do what @congusbongus said or simply rotate your sprite by 90 degrees in a photo editor...

Comment: Also, the title is now incorrect. It's not rotating a perfect 90 degrees all the time. Sometimes it's less, sometimes it's more.

Comment: I guess the root of the problem is pretty much the same as here: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/22167/how-can-i-make-a-sprite-move-in-the-direction-its-facing-using-radians/22186

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out my sprites weren't being drawn at the correct position, so their rotation was happening incorrectly. Let the lesson be *Always Draw At Your Sprite's Origin Because Bad Things Will Happen If You Don't Know What You're Doing.*

Answer (score 1):

Add this to your `Sprite` creation:

```
spatial.rotate90(false);
```

This will rotate the sprite's texture 90 degrees. From the docs:

> Rotates this sprite 90 degrees in-place by rotating the texture coordinates. This rotation is unaffected by setRotation(float) and rotate(float).

Comment: I appreciate this answer is quite succinct as it is, but maybe expand on it by using his code and providing a full code answer so that the answer itself can stand on its own.

Comment: @Blue I updated the answer

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! I tried that and it's certainly _closer_ to what I want, but not quite there. [Notice in this GIF](http://i.imgur.com/Xl7xxAH.gif) how it will lag behind or jump ahead from the cursor position. It may be related to my use of the OrthographicCamera. I'm not sure. I'm a bit stumped. Thank you for your help, though!

Comment: In your seconds GIF I think the problem comes from your algorithm, not from the sprite rotation (with my changes)